# GlobalPayments HPP - Currency CAD not allowed

Tags: global-payments-api

I'm learning the GlobalPayments credit card payment process by taking their existing sample HTML  structure and dynamically stuffing relevant values from my code into it. Once it's all built out then I throw it to the browser and submit the data.

This is the Global Payments sample....
[image: This is a portion of their sample form.]

Here is my dynamically generated form (scrubbed) which doesn't seem to work due to CURRENCY value.

```
<form action="https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay" method="POST" target="iframe">
     <input type='hidden' name='TIMESTAMP' value='20210512115612' />
    <input type='hidden' name='MERCHANT_ID' value='MYID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='ORDER_ID' value='MYORDERID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='AMOUNT' value='4000' />
    <input type='hidden' name='AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_VERSION' value='2' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_CHANNEL' value='ECOM' />
    <input type='hidden' name='COMMENT1' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_LANG' value='en' />
    <input type='hidden' name='CURRENCY' value='CAD' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_CUSTOMER_EMAIL' value='test@test.com' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_STREET1' value='123 Park Est ' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_STREET2' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_STREET3' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_CITY' value='My City' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_POSTALCODE' value='12345' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_BILLING_COUNTRY' value='124' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HPP_CHALLENGE_REQUEST_INDICATOR' value='NO_PREFERENCE' />
    <input type='hidden' name='MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL' value='TARGET URL' />
    <input type='hidden' name='SHA1HASH' value='MY HASH' />
    <input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME" value="Custom Field Data">
  <input type="submit" value="Click To Pay">
</form>
```

Every time I submit my form, I get **Currency CAD not allowed**, even though the country is Canada and the CURRENCY is set to CAD. I've tried every derivative including the currency code (124)....nothing works. I don't have any other problems but this...so far...any insight on why this would be happening would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that Canadian dollar (CAD) doesn't work but US dollar (USD) does. I've modified to use USD in the sandbox for now. You'd think that this little thing shouldn't matter. Global Payments documentation is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new GP-API it's not yet available for Canada.. only USA for now. Canada will be available later this year.

Source: Global Pay phone support